# Emacs: Disabling a minor mode from a file header

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, autofill

Though I mostly hate auto-fill-mode, Org Mode makes a good case for using it, so I don't want to disable it for Org Mode by default.  However, I do have some Org files where I absolutely do not want it, and am sick of typing `M-x auto-etc` every time I open them.

I know you can pass variable to Emacs from file headers, and after a bit of searching I came up with [this document](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) from which I deduced that I want something like this:

```
-*- mode: Org; auto-fill-mode 0 -*-
```

as the first line of my file.  But not this exactly, because that gives me an error:

```
Malformed mode-line: "auto-fill-mode 0"
```

and auto-fill mode does not start up.

I am sure it is a simple error in syntax, but it would be nice to know the right way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
# -*- mode: Org; eval: (auto-fill-mode 0) -*- #
```

Note that the `#` characters are optional, I just prefer them for style reasons.

```
$ info emacs

48.2.4.1 Specifying File Variables:

Do not use the `mode' keyword for minor modes.  To enable or disable 
a minor mode in a local variables list, use the `eval' keyword with a
Lisp expression that runs the mode command (*note Minor Modes::).`
```

Comment: Why do you need the `eval` statement?  Isn't that what this notation a shorthand for anyway, so it is sort of like (eval (eval x)) ?

Comment: @Dmitri:  I have had issues with enabling minor modes that way.  Specifically when I try to use visual-line-mode.  The mode bar at the bottom of the buffer says "Wrap" as if I was in visual line mode, but the lines do not wrap as expected.  I haven't looked into it any further, but I have not had issues when I do it this way.

Comment: The difference may lie in the fact that auto-fill mode does not take effect right away in that it does not affect anything until the first time that I press space/enter at a point past the fill column.  Visual-line mode however needs to take action right away because it visually wraps all of the lines that extend past the edge of the buffer.

Comment: This is the recommended way to enable/disable minor modes from file-local variables, so if you encounter problems with it, please report them via `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`.

Comment: @Stefan: You were misinformed.  I filed a bug and received a prompt reply from GNU which referred me to section 48.2.4.1 of `info emacs`.  See the update to my post for the relevant text.

Comment: @nispio: I don't see the relevance: you use the "mode" keyword to set the Org mode, but not to enable the minor mode.  For that, you use "eval", which is exactly what your quoted material recommends.  I have the impression we're mis-communicating.

Comment: @Stefan:  Okay, I think I get what the miscommunication is.  I was suggesting that when I use `-*- visual-line-mode: t -*-` I get strange behavior.  The syntax that I use in this post is the recommended method, and I ***have not*** had issues with that syntax.  :)

Comment: @nispio: OK, good, so we were in violent agreement from the get go.

Answer (score 5):

As per this part of the [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), append this to the end of your file:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (auto-fill-mode 0)
# End:
```

Comment: This does work.  Unfortunately, in Org Mode files, something at the end of the buffer will get folded into the last item in the list, and so you have to go hunt for it.  This is why for Org files, I would like to have all the settings in the preamble.

Comment: To make it clear that you have "system settings" at the end of your Org file, you could add an Org section, say "* Local Variables" and COMMENT it, so that it never will be exported.

Comment: @Dmitri, just use section tagged with `:noexport:` in the very end.

Answer (score 4):

[You are missing a colon](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html):

```
-*- mode: Org; auto-fill-mode: 0; -*-
```

Comment: That just works for setting variables, not enabling minor modes, right?

Comment: It does work to enable/disable minor modes.  In fact, I get a dialogue asking me if it is "safe," and, if so, it can save that to a variable in my .emacs file.  Cool!  And thanks.
`

Comment: Personally, I get mixed behavior when I enable minor modes this way, Just be aware that this might not always work.